# Can I import a calendar and have that count toward my free / busy

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, google-workspace-for-business

In Google Calendar you can import other calendars into your display. For example, I imported my personal calendar into my work calendar.

However, items from imported calendars are not taken into account when people are scheduling meetings. It appears like it only takes into account your primary calendar.

Is there a way to change Google Calendar so that when people book me for meetings my free / busy time takes into account other, imported calendar?